# Is a UAE Tourist visa still valid after a change of passport number?

Tags: visas, uae, passport-renewals, zimbabwean-citizens

I recently applied for a tourist/visit visa to UAE. The passport I applied with, whose number is on the e-visa I received, is damaged so I couldn't even fly there.

If I get a new passport, is that going to be a problem with Immigration?

Will they allow entry, since I now have a new passport with a number different from that on the visa?

Comment: I am Zimbabwean

Comment: Have you heard of simiĺar situations and how might tbey have been tackled

Answer (score 5):

I work closely with the immigration systems of UAE on the software development side. The following applies to you:

- Once you get your new passport, then your passport number is changed; that means that your UAE visa is no longer valid.
- There is no process in UAE immigration system to transfer the visit visa to a new passport. However, this can be done for residence/employment visas (not applicable to you).
- You cannot get a new visa until the previous one is cancelled. Ask your visa sponsor to cancel the visa if you wish to obtain new visa before expiry of current visa.
- Cancellation is not required if new visa is obtained after expiry of old visa.